# How to solve a trino error reading avro data

Tags: redis, avro, trino

I am using trino to read avro data from redis and report an error. I have configured the relevant data configuration file and followed the official tutorial of trino, but it still shows that the file cannot be recognized. Does anyone have a similar problem?

```
trino.exceptions.TrinoQueryError: TrinoQueryError(type=INTERNAL_ERROR, name=GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR, message="dataSchema cannot be null", query_id=20230613_020229_00001_fkdvc)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUtdF.png)

hope to get an answer